# Get child state when the action is triggered in parent component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get the state of child component when the button is clicked in the parent component.
child component handles its own states. but when an action is triggered in the parent component I want the data of a child component

the code snippet in the simplest form as this and I can't change the component architecture

```
const Child = (props) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("")
    return (
        <input value={name} onChange={(e) => { setName(e.target.value) }} />
    )
}

const parent = (props) => {
    const abc=()=>{
        // i want the name value here
    }
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Child />
            <button onClick={()=>{abc()}}>Abc</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on your use case? Why do you want the parent to have the child's state?

Comment: the use case is my child component has some form data and the button is next button so when I click next button I want the form data back to this component as it for update  and i can't put the next button in child component or child state in parent component

Comment: Do you have a form and you want to submit it from parent ?

Comment: yes kind of that

Answer (score 1):

As with most problems, there are multiple ways to solve this one. Each solution will be more appropriate and readable for a different use case.

One option would be to move the state into the parent component.

```
const Child = (props) => {
    return (
        <input value={props.name} onChange={(e) => { props.setName(e.target.value) }} />
    )
}

const parent = (props) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("")
    const abc=()=>{
        // i want the name value here
    }
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Child name={name} setName={setName} />
            <button onClick={()=>{abc()}}>Abc</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Another method would be to use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). [More documentation on this use case](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables)

```
const Child = (props) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("")
    props.nameRef.current = name
    return (
        <input value={name} onChange={(e) => { setName(e.target.value) }} />
    )
}

const parent = (props) => {
    const nameRef = useRef("");
    const abc=()=>{
        // i want the name value here
    }
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Child  nameRef={nameRef}/>
            <button onClick={()=>{abc()}} >Abc</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

IMHO most of the time you should use the first one. However, if it makes the code more readable for the state to live in the child component, or it would take too much time to refactor, then the second example works as well.

Comment: Ty for the approach i was looking for the second approach

Answer (score 0):

```
const Child = (props) => {

    return (
        <input value={name} onChange={e =>  setName(e.target.value) } />
    )
}

const parent = (props) => {
const [name, setName] = useState("")
    const abc=()=>{
        // i want the name value here
    }
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Child setName={setName}/>
            <button onClick={()=>{abc()}}>Abc</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: i cant put child state in parent component this is a simple form of my complex child component. i need to handle the child states in the child component itself